# How to factorise $x^4$ equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[This is my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335985/inverse-function-g-1)

I'm facing a problem to factorise this $64x^4+64x^3-88x^2-51x+39=0$.
How to factorise $x^4$ equations?

Comment: Given a root of your polynomial (however you get that..guessing or use [Ferrari's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation)) and do [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)...

Comment: You can factorize it as: $(4x^2+3x-3)(16x^2+4x-13)$.

Comment: You could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quartic_Formula.svg

Comment: [General method, but overkill in this case](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/3810/346_050.pdf)

Comment: You might take a look at my answer to your previous question. It removes the necessity to solve the proposed quartic equation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't find rational roots with the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), your next bet for solving this on paper is to factor the quartic into two quadratic equations. For example, in this case, we can let 
$$
64x^4 + 64x^3 - 88x^2 - 51x + 39 = (ax^2 + bx + c)(px^2 + qx + r)
$$
Note that, by comparing coefficients, we can tell that $ap = 64$, $cr = 39$, $br + cq = -51$, $aq + bp = 64$, $ar + bq + cp = -88$.

There are only a few values of $a,c, p, r$ that satisfy the first two equations. After some guessing and checking (kind of like the guessing and checking that goes into factoring a quadratic**), we find that 
$$
64x^4 + 64x^3 - 88x^2 - 51x + 39 = (4x^2 + 3x - 3)(16x^2 + 4x - 13)
$$

And you can finish by solving the two quadratics.

** Of course, this is a bit more involved than solving a quadratic. While there aren't many ways to simplify this process, you can make some educated guesses. For example, you can tell things about negative/positive, perhaps whether numbers are even/odd, etc. Things that make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) which always gives the solutions to quartic equations. Though the solutions won't be pretty...I get $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{8}\pm \frac{\sqrt{53}}{8}, x_{3,4}=-\frac{3}{8}\pm\frac{\sqrt{57}}{8}.$$